How to Override Cart Pickup Options in Custom Cart Item Component
I’m working on a project using SAP Spartacus Storefront 2211, and I’m trying to override the cart pickup options in the cart page. By default, the cart pickup options work properly when I don’t customize the cart item component. However, after creating a custom cart item component, I’m having trouble implementing the pickup options feature correctly.
Questions:

What could be the reason the cx-cart-pickup-options-container is not working in my custom component?
Is there a specific way to integrate the CartPickupOptionsContainerComponent in a custom cart item component?
Are there additional steps or configurations needed to make this work?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Created a Custom Component:
I created a custom cart pick-up container component and extended CartPickupOptionsContainerComponent.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CartPickupOptionsContainerComponent,
  CartPickupOptionsContainerModule,
  PickupOptionsModule,
} from '@spartacus/pickup-in-store/components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-cart-pick-up-container',
  templateUrl: './custom-cart-pick-up-container.component.html',
  styleUrl: './custom-cart-pick-up-container.component.scss',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CartPickupOptionsContainerModule,
    PickupOptionsModule,
  ],
})
export class CustomCartPickUpContainerComponent extends CartPickupOptionsContainerComponent {}


Updated the HTML:
I added the custom cart pick-up container component in my HTML.
<cx-cart-pickup-options-container></cx-cart-pickup-options-container>



Despite these steps, the cart pickup options are not working as expected in my custom cart item component. I expected the cx-cart-pickup-options-container to render the pickup options, but it doesn’t seem to be functioning properly.

please explain with more code, what is the parent code, have you added it to imports array? what is the HTML you have shared please share the file name

I created an app-custom-cart-item component, which is the parent component. Besides product details like name and SKU, I need to implement the  component, which by default has cx-pickup-options inside. I have imported the necessary modules: CartPickupOptionsContainerModule and PickupOptionsModule. As you can see in the imports array, that’s why I am able to use  in its HTML file. However, it doesn’t work.

So i created custom app-custom-cart-pick-up-container and implemented it inside app-custom-cart-item component
